# A car goes from point A to point B exactly in three hours with $x(t)={59\over 3}t^2-t^3$ .Find the average velocity

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

A car goes from point A to point B exactly in three hours.We assume that the car is moving in a straight line and that the distance of $x(t)$ from A at time $t$ ( where time is measured in hours and the distance in kilometers ) is given by the function $x(t)={59\over 3}t^2-t^3$.

$i)$what is the average velocity on this route?

$ii)$what is the instantaneous velocity of the car at the time of reaching to point B ($t=3$)

Could anyone give me any ideas ir hints for these two questions?

Comment: https://www.google.si/?ion=1&espv=2#q=average%20velocity%20formula

Comment: The average velocity is $$\frac{\mbox{travelled space}}{\mbox{time}}=\frac{x(T)-x(0)}{T}$$ while the istantaneous velocity at time $t$ is $$v(t)=x'(t)$$ now simply apply the formulas.

Comment: for the first question the answer is $u(t)$ and for the second i ll do $u(3)$?

Answer (score 1):

i) Average velocity is simply $$\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{x(3)-x(0)}{3-0}$$

ii) The instantaneous velocity $v(t)$ is the derivative of $x(t)$ w.r.t. to $t$. Then the instantaneous velocity at point B (where $t=3$) is just $v(3)$.

Comment: for the first we want average velocity generally not at $t=3$

Comment: @MantolInis Are you sure? If you have written the problem as it has been given to you, I don't this it is the case (it says "on *this* route"). But otherwise just let $3 \rightarrow t_f$ where $t_f$ is "the time at arriving at the destination" and you have the general expression.

Comment: i think that average velocity is the $u(t)$ from theory

Comment: @What is $u(t)$?? It doesn't matter whether we call the instantaneous velocity $u(t), v(t)$ or $\text{whatever}(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Average velocity is just distance divided by time. Instantaneous velocity is $\frac {dx}{ft}$

Answer (score -1):

First of
$$v(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$$
Which means in your case:
$$v(t)=\frac{118}{3}t -3t^2$$

I am assuming x(t) is given in units of $[x]=m$ and that means $v(t)$ will be in $[v]=\frac{m}{sec}$. If you want to find $v(3_{[hours]})$ you have to translate $t$ to units of $[t]=sec$ and then assert $t=\text{Translated Value}=t'$.

For the Average speed:
$$v_{Average}=\frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} v(t)dt$$

In this case:
$$v_{Average}=\frac{1}{t'-0}\int_{0}^{t'} v(t)dt$$
$$\int v(t)dt=x(t)+c \implies v_{Average}=\frac{1}{t'-0}\cdot \left[x(t')-x(0)\right]$$

Comment: Just to let you know: You can use \text{} for writing non-italicized text within a math environment (so \text{translated Value}). Also the convention w.r.t. specifying units would be (force in Newtons is used as an example) [F]=N. So the brackets do not go around the unit names themselves. Cheers.

Comment: average speed is not only the $u(t)$?

Comment: @MantolInis I didn't understand your question. Did you mean to ask if it is only defined in $[0,\infty)$?